# Missing security menu in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I want to make use of the TFS API to retrieve information about builds/commits etc. As I follow [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/samples), I see that I first need to [create a security token for my user.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/overview)

However, nowhere in my TFS web interface I can find where to configure the security of my user.

Any tips? What do I miss?

P.s. I use TFS on-premise, not Team Services (should not make difference though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be . From your **home page**, open your profile. Go to your  **security** details.  Add the screenshot of my TFS2017 for your reference:

[image]

***Note:*** Personal access tokens are only available with TFS 2017 and above or VS Team service. It's not support in TFS2015.

When pointing to TFS2015 or TFS2013, you may have to  pass a username and password (could masked as a secret variable) in your script instead of using personal access tokens. For a sample you can refer below links:

- [VSTS/TFS REST API: The basics and working with builds and releases](http://blog.nwcadence.com/vststfs-rest-api-the-basics-and-working-with-builds-and-releases/)
- [TFS 2013.4 On-Premise. Enable Basic Authentication to access Tfs
  REST Api](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6c965b5-3ef2-4440-a5e2-10de3fe60ad7/tfs-20134-onpremise-enable-basic-authentication-to-access-tfs-rest-api?forum=tee)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have "Security" option in my instance (I use tfs2015 btw)

Comment: You question is related to TFS2017. And have added the 2017 tag. **Personal access tokens** are only available with TFS 2017 or Team service....

Comment: When pointing to TFS2015, you may have to  pass a username and password (masked as a secret variable) in your script instead of using personal access tokens. For a sample you can refer below links: http://blog.nwcadence.com/vststfs-rest-api-the-basics-and-working-with-builds-and-releases/ & https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b6c965b5-3ef2-4440-a5e2-10de3fe60ad7/tfs-20134-onpremise-enable-basic-authentication-to-access-tfs-rest-api?forum=tee